# PHP - How can I check if a date lies between two existing dates?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a booking page that takes an input of check in and check out date from the user as well as the room number.

This is my current code; its current function is to get all bookings for a selected room number and check all its date ranges to see one of the current bookings overlaps the user input dates. if it overlaps then echo an error otherwise do nothing. :

```
$sql18 = "SELECT rid, checkin, checkout FROM bookings
    WHERE rid = $rNumber";    //$rNumber is room number obtained from a dropdown list
$results18 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql18);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results18)) {
    if (('$cInDate' >= $row["checkin"] && '$cInDate' < $row["checkout"]) ||  //$cInDate and $cOutDate are user inputs
        ('$cOutDate' > $row["checkin"] && '$cOutDate' <= $row["checkout"])) {
        echo "invalid booking";
    }
}
```

i tested the if statement to trigger the error with no luck. i am still getting past the if statement with no errors

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use the `between` function in your query. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: For starts you should remove the '' in $cOutDate and $cInDate, if you use it like that '$cInDate' you are comparing it as a string

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @nanjero echizen.. no need of if you can check status in query itself

Comment: If possible, always try to go for query rather than php code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of comparing in php, you can do that in you mysql query.

```
$sql18 = "SELECT rid, checkin, checkout 
FROM bookings
WHERE rid = $rNumber 
AND checkin <= '{$row['checkout']}' 
AND checkout => '{$row['checkin']}'";
```

As you are comparing in two dates with two dates, you can use cross comparison, compare `checkin` column with `checkout` date, and `checkout` column with `checkin` date, as shown in above query.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to execute below query. I hope it will give you proper records.
Please check and let me know.

```
$sql18 = "SELECT rid,checkin,checkout 
FROM bookings WHERE 
rid = $rNumber 
AND checkin <='".$cInDate."' 
AND checkout >='".$cInDate."' 
AND checkin  <='".$cOutDate."' 
AND checkout >'".$cOutDate."'";    //$rNumber is

$results18 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql18);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use between function within your SQL query only?

Your SQL query should look like this

```
$sql18 = "SELECT 
rid, checkin, checkout 
FROM bookings
WHERE rid = $rNumber AND
(checkin BETWEEN $cInDate AND $cOutDate) AND
(checkout BETWEEN $cInDate AND $cOutDate)";
```

This will return if there is any booking made of particular time.

Avoid using plain PHP variables in your SQL query, it causes SQL injection problems.

Comment: Try to echo out `$sql18` and run the same query string in your mysql client, Do you see any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, in your query itself we can find validity of booking of a particular room..

```
SELECT A.*,(CASE WHEN A.checkin >= '$cInDate' && A.checkin <= '$cOutDate'
&& A.checkout >= '$cInDate' && A.checkout <= '$cOutDate' THEN 'Valid' ELSE 'Invalid' END) 
AS Roomstatus FROM booking A WHERE A.rid='$rNumber'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything right nanjero. Only thing is in if condition you used variable with in single quotes so that it will think as string so only its not working. It have checked with some static data it was working. please go through following code.

```
$cInDate = '2016-11-03';
$cOutDate = '2016-11-08';
$rNumber = 'G01';

$sql18 = "SELECT rid, checkin, checkout FROM bookings
    WHERE rid = '$rNumber'";    //$rNumber is room number obtained from a dropdown list
$results18 = mysqli_query($con, $sql18);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results18)) {
    if (($cInDate >= $row["checkin"] && $cInDate <= $row["checkout"]) ||  //$cInDate and $cOutDate are user inputs
        ($cOutDate > $row["checkin"] && $cOutDate <= $row["checkout"])) {
        echo "invalid booking";
    }
}
```

even it is working. Better you can go with strtotime function for comparing. Any queries comment me.